# Resetting an identity field every time a stored procedure is executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have a stored procedure which populates a table with an identity field with an increment of 1. At the end of the stored procedure I want to reset the identity field with a standard command like this. This will prevent the identity field value growing exponentially.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( dbo.table_name, RESEED, 0 )
```

If the stored procedure is called on a regular basis by end users what are the implications of doing what I propose, if any?
For argument's sake, if two users called the stored procedure at exactly the same point in time is there a minute chance it could cause a problem for one or both users?
Or maybe there is a more secure way to do this?

Comment: What is the usage of the identity field in the table? Is your identity field also the `primary key`. If that's the case then this will break the uniqueness and generate error. When you say 'growing exponentially', how much data are we talking about? If the number of records will be large, you can set the field to be of datatype `bigint`.

Comment: @Amit the table in question is being used as a holding area for data being processed by the stored procedure. At the end of the stored procedure the data is deleted from the table as well as reseeding the identity field

Comment: If it is staging/holding area, then you really don't need an identity field but can you elaborate what is the usage of this field.

Comment: @Amit the identity column is used for ordering the data in the table, so it needs to be incremented doesn't it, or is there another way like using a integer variable, setting it to 1, then incrementing the column value by 1 for  each subsequent row in the table? The number of rows is variable each time.

Comment: I think you will have to explain your process in a bit more detail. Why do you want the data to be ordered in the staging table? You should be using some field from the source data itself to order the records. This field will not be present in the target table, therefore ordering the records by this field will not make any sense.

Comment: @Amit OK I'm not at my desk right now, but I'll check it and post back here. In the meantime thank you for your time.

Comment: Utilize ROW_NUMBER() function for results specific/unique ordering. There is no sense in involving an identity value that does not have any use any usage outside of a single sproc.  To avoid collision with other executions, use a composite key to the results (eg. User ID and ROW_NUMBER() values) for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. In the end I retained the integer column, but made it nullable, and populated it using a int varaiable like this UPDATE dbo.table_name SET intVariable = myID = intVariable + 1 this seems to work fine